# How to mirror a rigged right hand to create a rigged left hand

Tags: mirror-modifier

I have made a rigged right hand for a character and I'm trying to mirror it to make a left hand. Please refer to the image
[image: trying to mirror a hand]

It doesn't seem as if I could use the mirror modifier to do this. If I select everything the modifier tab disappears. I tried to do this in a seperate file that only contains the hand and its rig, and selected the parts of the hand without the rig; was able to add a mirror modifier but as soon as I tried to select a reference object I get an error message at the bottom saying failed to set value.

Please help me with this.

Comment: How did you rig your character, is your character made of one object or several objects?

Comment: @moonboots every piece of armour or body part is its own object and is directly parented to a bone, there's no armature deform. it's the same with the hand, every segment is parented to a bone individually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *Edit* mode, name your bones correctly (with the _R or .R suffixe for the right limbs), select all and go into the *Armature panel > Symmetrize*:

[image]

Select your objects, duplicate with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> and in the *Object panel > Mirror > Global X* (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>M</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>):

[image]

Now parent each limb to each bone: Select the object, shift select the armature, switch it to *Pose* mode, select the good bone and *Set Parent to > Bone*.

**Second solution:** Symmetrize the armature, join all your objects into one, remove one half, give it a *Mirror* modifier in order to symmetrize:

[image]

Now parent the *Object* to the armature *With Empty Groups*. It creates an *Armature* modifier under the *Mirror* and it generates a series of vertex groups in your mesh, but for the moment the vertices are not assigned to any vertex group. Select a finger with <kbd>L</kbd>, select the vertex group to which it is supposed to be assigned to (here *f1_R*) and click on the *Assign* button:

[image]

When you have finished with one side, the opposite side  will work as well, you can apply the *Mirror* modifier.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! However, when I try to Symmetrize nothing happens, there's no dupliated symmetrical armature like in your images

Comment: have you correctly named your bones?

Comment: It works now after I named the bone in the format in your image! I'm following the next step thanks!

Comment: @Egoless If this answer was satisfactory, please click the check mark by the top left of the answer to show it is what you wanted.

Comment: can I maybe ask if there is any possible way to avoid having to redo the parenting individually for each bone? Is it possible to have the parented relationships between the objects and the bones mirrored across too? (because the hand has 30+ joints...)

Comment: @BentleyCarpenter yes, surely, thanks for the reminder. As I'm fairly unfamiliar with stackexchange, can I ask if the question will close if I check mark an answer? The answer is very good but I'm trying to get information on if I could automate the entire process because manually doing the parenting again is a lot of workload

Comment: not that I know, it would have been easier if you had a unique object mirrored with a Mirror modifier and parented With Empty Groups, the parenting would have been automatic, but it's another way of parenting

Comment: @moonboots could you shed some light on how to do the empty groups thing or point me to where I can learn this?

Comment: ok I'll edit my answer

Comment: thank you so much!